# WordPress – site with 2 stylesheets and more…

Tags: menus, pages, css

I’m building a site that is broken up into two views (or sections): **College** and **Corporate**.
» [See it here](http://publicidentity.bldg13.com/)

When the **College** tab is active, the site will use **college-styles.css** (orange background)
When the **Corporate** tab is active, the site will use **corporate-styles.css** (blue background)

Some pages are global (content is the same for `college/corporate`)
Some pages are specific (content is different for `college/corporate`)

So there will be one navigation set up for college and one for corporate

Also, ideally the pages/links will be as follows:

- `/college/why-us`
- `/college/who-are-we`
- `/college/how-we-do-it`
- `/college/our-work`
- `/college/our-blog`
- `/college/connect`
- `/corporate/why-us`
- `/corporate/who-are-we`
- `/corporate/how-we-do-it`
- `/corporate/our-work`
- `/corporate/our-blog`
- `/corporate/connect`

What is the best way to handle this? I remember a few years back where it was popular for sites to have two stylesheets (usually a light and dark version) and allow the user to select one. But I need more than just a style switcher, I need to load a whole new page and navigation. Also, ideally there would be a way to not have to create duplicate pages for the ones that are “global”.

#### Global pages

- `who-we-are`
- `how-we-do-it`
- `our-blog`
- `connect`

#### Specific pages

- `why-us-college`
- `why-us-corporate`
- `our-work-college`
- `our-work-corporate`

One way that was suggested was to create a blank college page and a blank corporate page and then make a college version of every page (`why-us-colloge`, `who-we-are-college`, etc.), a corporate version of every page and make them child pages of college/corporate. But I don’t really want a separate blog for both, nor a separate connect page for both.

Thoughts, ideas? Any help/input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create WordPress template with name College & Corporate respectively.

Then add some code in your `header.php`. Refer [`is_page_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template). With this method WordPress will identify which template you are using and will apply CSS related to it.

You can use Default template for rest of the pages.